# How do I keep bindings from firing TextChanged event?

Tags: c#, data-binding, textchanged

I'm using the Control.TextChanged event to detect when the user has modified the form. I have a method that loops through every control and adds the same TextChanged to all the controls.

My problem is, on the form I also have databinding that binds bindings that have Binding.Format() and Binding.Parse(), and these are within a TabControl. If the user changes tabs (SelectedIndexChanged), it then activates the Format/Parse and fires the TextChanged event which makes it seem like the form's been modified!

How can I either (1) keep the bindings or Binding.Format and .Parse from firing the TextChanged event, or (2) implement a better way to detect of the controls on the form have been modified?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the actual `TextChanged` Event, check the backing properties and look at when they change. You can make use of `INotifyPropertyChanged` to help out with this.

Comment: Hmm... Could you possibly provide an example of this for me, please? I MSDN'ed the iNPC, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it for what I'm trying to do. It isn't as clear to me how I can use that property.

Comment: Does it involve in any way the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184414.aspx of "How to: Raise Change Notifications Using a BindingSource and the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface?"